# How to edit ListIndex property of a ListBox?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I cannot change directly *ListIndex* since it's read-only.

After searches, I found this

```
lstEnergieBatiment.Selected(0) = True
```

which will highlight it but not select it.

I need the property `ListIndex` to be edited since depending on user actions, it may be read right after.

How can I achieve this?

This Listbox allow multiple selections.

Comment: Can you explain the UI issue? I think I've asked two similar questions but not with `ListIndex`. If you're emulating a single-select user-click just set the value of the listbox to the control source ID, and use `.Selected` to highlight the row. I am not sure what to do with multi-select, as setting the value of the control wouldn't work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657279/5936117) was helpful for me to figure out how to achieve my goals but they may not overlap your issue.

Comment: Clearly, I should review that myself...

Comment: thx!! however I can't believe there is not a simple way just like Index = 0. I mean it's supposed to be simple task?

Comment: Is the listbox multi-select?

Comment: yes!! I edited to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not edit listindex. The system sets listindex to indicate which item is selected by the user. As you handle `multiselect`, you'd rather use this to see which items are selected:

```
For i = 0 To LBX.ListCount - 1
    If LBX.Selected(i) Then
    ' whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this.

```
Dim Item As Variant
For Each Item In Me.List.ItemsSelected
    Debug.Print Me.List.ItemData(Item)
Next Item
```